# Can you cross Live and Neutral traces on opposite sides of a PCB?

Tags: voltage, pcb-design, mains, safety, pcb-layers

Can 230V live and neutral traces be crossed over if they are on the top and bottom side of a PCB?

I know there are requirements for creepage and clearance; if that requirement is less than the thickness of the PCB, is it ok and safe? Do the requirements apply through the PCB laminate?

Comment: That depends on the PCB material and it's thickness. A quick google search came up with [this document](https://www.magazines007.com/pdf/High-Voltage-PCDesign.pdf). "FR4 has an initial dielectric rating of 800-900 Volts per mil but due to aging effects, a more realistic value is only 300 Volts." (Note it sais mil, not mm).

Comment: @Unimportant You should post that as an answer with some quotes from the link.